# No qualifying bean of type ScheduledExecutorService | TaskScheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

Here is the Scheduling Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class RWInventorySchedule {

protected org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RWInventorySchedule.class);

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;


   @Bean
   public RWInventoryProcessor constructInventoryProcessor() {
       log.debug("RWInventorySchedule constructs InventoryProcessor, entityManager : {} " , entityManager);
       return new RWInventoryProcessor(entityManager);
    }
}
```

Inventory Processor is the following

```
public class RWInventoryProcessor  {
 ...
 @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000,initialDelay = 3000)
 @Transactional
 public void runProcess() {
   ...
 }
}
```

During execution, getting the following errors in debug log

> DEBUG
>   org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
>   - Could not find default TaskScheduler bean org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler'
>   available
>   
>  
>   ...
>   DEBUG org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
>   - Could not find default ScheduledExecutorService bean org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService' available

Am I missing anything

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're using Java configuration you need an @Bean definition for the type of scheduler you wish to use. Spring does not have a default bean for this. For example

```
@Bean
public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    return new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(); //single threaded by default
}
```

Comment: you mean additionally along with `RWInventoryProcessor` @Bean method ? or I need to extend | implement `RWInventoryProcessor` my with `ConcurrentTaskScheduler`

Comment: In any class that is annotated with @Configuration and picked up with Spring, so yes could be alongside RWInventoryProcessor

Comment: Perfect, Here some detailed explanation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html.

Comment: One more question related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791023/spring-trigger-notify-explicitly-a-scheduled-method could you check

Answer (score 0):

I have used this form my xml Spring Configuration:

```
<task:annotation-driven  executor="executor" />

<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10"/>

<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="7"/>
```

My Component processor is:

```
@Component
public class QueueConsumer {

    @Autowired
    ProcessQueue queue;

    @Autowired
    TaskProcessor processor;

    @Autowired
    TaskResultRepository resultRepository;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 15000)
    public void runJob() {
        ProcessTask task = queue.poll();
        ...
    }
}
```

You need the annotation equivalent to `<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10"/>`