# Spring trigger/notify explicitly a Scheduled method

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

Transactions likes sales and purchase that are created via REST

```
@Component
@Path("txns")
public class Transaction {

 @Path("/purchases")
 public Response postPurchaseTrnsaction(Transaction txn) {
    // persistence takes place here
 }

 @Path("/sales")
 public Response postSalesTrnsaction(Transaction txn) {
    // persistence takes place here
 }     
}
```

There is a separate Background Inventory process that updates Inventory of SKUs which are sold or purchased from the above trnsactions.

```
public class InventoryProcessor {

  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 900000,initialDelay = 3000) // 15 mins
  @Transactional
  public void doInventory() {
    // open Transactions, update inventory records
  }

}
```

This process runs every 15 mins. However, whenever a new transactions arrive, need to trigger or notify the `InventoryProcessor` `doInventory` method explicitly to perform inventory immediately.

Is there a option in spring.

Answer (score 0):

Can you inject InventoryProcessor into Transaction and call the method programatically? Or wrap the call in another method marked @Async if it needs to be done asynchronously.

```
@Component
@Path("txns")
public class Transaction {

 @Inject
 private InventoryProcessor inventoryProcessor

 @Path("/purchases")
 public Response postPurchaseTrnsaction(Transaction txn) {
    // persistence takes place here

    inventoryProcessor.doInventory();
 }

 @Path("/sales")
 public Response postSalesTrnsaction(Transaction txn) {
    // persistence takes place here
 }     
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate bit more

Comment: Can not, Request can not wait until inventory processor complete. inventory processor is time consuming process

Answer (score 0):

You can implement observer pattern using [ApplicationEventPulistherAware](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.2.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEventPublisherAware.html) in your inventory Processor and have your transaction functions publish the custom events through an implementation of ApplicationEventPublisher